# "percentage of students" vs . "percentage of the students"

Tags: articles, definite-article, determiners

Is it:

> International students represent no more than 15% **of the students** that
>   select math as a major.

Or

> International students represent no more than 15% **of students** that
>   select math as a major.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include a "determiner" *(**the, those**)* or not in your cited context. But I suspect that *on average*, most writers *wouldn't* (and those that *do* would probably be more likely to use ***those*** than ***the*** anyway).

You might find [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+people+that+do%2Cof+the+people+who+do%2Cof+those+people+that+do%2Cof+those+people+who+do%2Cof+people+that+do%2Cof+people+who+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) useful. Among other things, it suggests that *most* writers would use ***who*** rather than ***that*** in your cited context.

<sub>(transcribed directly from earlier comments)</sub>